# Does push notification cause a continuous polling on server?

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, polling, firebase-cloud-messaging, server-push

I am using Google Channel to do Push notification from server. It's working fine, but when I open the debugger windows, I can see lot of polling request that are going to the server.

Is that the way push notification works? If yes, then what is the use of it?

```
var token ="<%token%>";// This will creaete unique identifier(some id created by google api + ur key)

   channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);    
       socket = channel.open();    

   socket.onopen = function() {

     $('#messages').append('<p>Connected!</p>'); 

   };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GCM doesn't do that. Gonna refer to the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm#lifecycle) on it's flow.

> **Lifecycle Flow**
>
> - Send and receive downstream messages.
>
>   - Send a message. The app server sends messages to the client app:
>
>     1. The app server sends a message to GCM connection servers.
>     2. The GCM connection server enqueues and stores the message if the device is offline.
>     3. When the device is online, the GCM connection server sends the message to the device.
>     4. On the device, the client app receives the message according to the platform-specific implementation. See your platform-specific documentation for details.
>   - Receive a message. A client app receives a message from a GCM connection server.

Also announced in the recent I/O 2016, GCM's successor is now [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), which not only has the Push Notification Service, but also has other features (one example is Analytics) for free.

So overall, using GCM (or FCM) is a simpler method than polling. It handles the queuing of the messages you sent, and some others.

---

*Part of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193888/4625829). Also includes an idea why [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) is not ideal when sending push notifications.*