# What exactly is Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to retrieve data from firebase database while app is in background or closed. For this, I have been thinking of using database reference in a service.

Instead of this, people recommend using Firebase Cloud Messaging. But what exactly is that?

How does is interact with the database? How do I use it for listening and retrieving data? There are very little explanation on these and firebase docs are too broad. Or maybe I just cant find it

Comment: The documentation is broad because the cloud messaging is a separate product than the database. That'd also explain why you can't find much. FCM is not necessary to use the database

Answer (score 3):

> *But what exactly is that?*

[Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) (FCM) is the latest version of [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) (GCM), which is Google's [Push Notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) Service.

It allows developers to send data from their *App Server* towards the *Client App*. For your case, you may be able to send over the desired data towards your Client App, by integrating your Database with FCM.

> *How does is interact with the database? How do I use it for listening and retrieving data?*

If you are using [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/), you may choose to integrate with FCM in such a way (referring to @FrankvanPuffelen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38294824/4625829)):

> Sending messages to devices based on inserts into the Firebase Database will require you to run a trusted process, typically on an app server that you control. This [trusted process listens to the database changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/retrieve-data) and then [calls Firebase Cloud Messaging to send the messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).
>
> For an example of how to send messaging from a node.js script, see my answer here: [How to send Firebase Cloud Messaging from a node server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38016652/how-to-send-firebase-cloud-messaging-from-a-node-server)

In summary, you don't use it to listen for data. You can however use it as the medium to send the data from your Database towards your Client App.

Comment: Can't I just instead use DatabaseReference in a class extending service ? What would be wrong with it?

Comment: @user6650650 Keeping a listener active for the Real-time database would also mean keeping an open socket on the user's device, which adds to battery consumption. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40401062/4625829).

Comment: How about adding a single value event listener ( another interface which retrieves data only once , not on every update at database ) periodically , like every 30 seconds ?

Comment: That's still like *Polling*. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38193888/4625829).

Comment: Also , how much battery cosumption would it cause?

Comment: That my friend, is a totally different concern from your post now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are implementing Firebase for the first time, I'd recommend you to go through [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and get a basic idea about it.

Broadly, FCM (previously GCM) is a **Cloud Messaging** service for your app. Most importantly, the **Analytics** and **Realtime Database** of Firebase are used.

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) is a link to their docs. Go through it for better understanding of Firebase and its implementation.

Comment: Firebase is a completely separate product than GCM. Firebase Realtime Database, that is, or the original product, Firebase Cloud Messaging is a rebranded GCM (and uses the existing technology called GCM)